# Options to retrieve an image size more 15 mb

Tags: image

what are different ways to read image size more than 15 MB, it can be either on CDN or any datastore.

1) Can we read in chunks and aggregate on the server, before returning response

Comment: You haven't given any information required to answer. Read how? To where? Through which transport?

Comment: Let's make the question general - What are the best ways to read an image size more than 15 MB